# Finite dimensional real division algebra up to isotopy

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, division-algebras, non-associative-algebras

Finite dimensional real division (non necessarily associative) algebras exist in dimensions 1, 2, 4, and 8. The standard example is a Hurwitz algebra $(A,*)$: reals, complexes, quaternions, octonions. Then one can do an isotope of $A$: pick three invertible linear operators $a,b,c$ and define a new multiplication by $x\star y = a(b(x)*c(y))$.

Reading [this 2015 paper by Darpo and Izquierdo](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/forum-2012-0087/html?lang=en), I have realised that many of the (real finite-dimensional) division algebras are isotopes of the Hurwitz algebras. I do not see why it should be true, in general, but I could not find any examples in the literature, which are not isotopes, either.

**Question 1:** In which dimensions, is it known whether every division algebra is an isotope of a Hurwitz algebra?

**Question 2:** Is there a classification of all real finite dimensional algebras up to isotopy?

Comment: Octonians are not associative.  Perhaps mention that you do not require "associative".

Comment: Could you maybe add a link to the paper title that is not paywalled or maybe just mention the paper title in the post?

Comment: Darpo, 2018  https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1849

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks!

Comment: Strange. One used to see MathSciNet links (but not reviews) without going through the paywall. I have changed a link to the journal: I cannot see this paper on the arxiv.

Comment: @BugsBunny: That was my recollection too. I guess It probably has something to do with the recent updates they did.